# MVC 5 and SQL Server date filter issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have datetime values in my database table like `05/05/2015 23:00:00`. I am putting date filter in my query and try to fetch all the data of `05/05/2015` like this:

```
select * 
from table 
where date <= "05/05/2015".
```

It's not returning the records which have value `05/05/2015 23:00:00` in database.

Please suggest the way..

Comment: 05/05/2015 is the same as 05/05/2015 00:00:00. Which is before 05/02/2015 23:00:00. Perhaps you want `< '20150506'` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Using this where clause here

```
where date <= "05/05/2015"
```

means: return every row with a `date` **before** 05/05/2015 (including the ones with 05/05/2015 00:00:00 - but nothing more).

If you want to get **all** records for that day, too, you should use

```
where date < '20150506'
```

I'd also recommend to use the **ISO-8601** date format `yyyyMMdd` to prevent any regional settings from interfering with your strings representing dates.

And I would also recommend to use something more **expressive** than just `date` for your column name - in SQL Server **2008** and newer, `DATE` is a reserved T-SQL keyword, too - use something like `HireDate`, `SaleDate` or something that tells you **want kind** of date this is

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Any other suggestion please?

Comment: @Nitinsoni: can you add some **sample data** to your question, and show us the query you're using, and what output you're getting from it?? Hard to diagnose without knowing **anything** about your data .....